# How can i change the font-size of my button in my modal form dialog jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqmodal

Here is my jqmodal form code:

```
$("#dialog-form").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,        //Shows dialog
    height: 300,
    width: 220,
    modal: true,
    fontSize: "100%",
    buttons: {
      "Save": function () {
        $(this).dialog('close');
          alert("Customer successfully added!");
           $.post('insertsup.php', $('#customer').serialize(), function(result){




}).css("font-size", "62.5%");   

        },
        "Cancel": function () 

        {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }



    }
```

How can I edit my font-size to 62.5% in the jqmodal including the button text size? please help me..

Comment: Can you create a http://jsfiddle.net version of you had tried?

Comment: wait a minute.. ill just update my post..

Comment: please help me here.. :(

Comment: hello? please help me here

Answer (score 0):

Please -- stop flagging these questions as jqModal. You are using jquery ui dialog!

That said; use CSS to change the font-size. Not javascript. Please include your markup (aka HTML) that includes your button element and I can provide guidance on that.

As an example;

```
<button style="font-size: 62.5%;">button text</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

several ways to fix this

`$("#dialog-form").css({"font-size": "62.5%"});` This ensures that all text belonging to the div #dialog-form has font-size of 62.5%. Of course if you have another div inside it with custom font properties you'll never see this change reflected in those child divs.

Another thing I noticed is that you're appending .css to the end of you jquery ui dialog/modal. I think you're suppose to treat it with {} per Jquery documentation [Jquery CSS API](http://api.jquery.com/css/) so the correct way would be `.css({"font-size": "62.5%"});`

Comment: i tried your answer sir but the button text size inside my dialog still big.

Comment: so is everything else fine and just the button text size big? if that is the case then I would just in my css do a new property `#button-div{
    font-size: 10px;
}`

or per their documentation they use the class name ui-button-text so the other way would be to `$(".ui-button-text").css({"font-size":"15px"});`